# Django-nose test results and coverage not being gathered and displayed in sonar

Tags: python, django, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a django project, which is wrapped in a maven build which handles packaging and publishing, as well as generating docs and other lifecycle tasks.

We have tests that are executed in django-nose that are exectued at the test phase of the maven lifecycle.

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
  '--with-coverage',
  '--cover-erase',
  '--cover-package={0}'.format(TEST_FOLDERS),
  '--cover-html',
  '--cover-branches',
  '--cover-html-dir=' + COVERAGE_WORK_FOLDER + 'coverage-reports/',
  '--cover-xml',
  '--cover-xml-file=' + COVERAGE_WORK_FOLDER + 'coverage.xml',
  '--with-xunit',
  '--xunit-file=' + COVERAGE_WORK_FOLDER + 'nosetests.xml',
]
```

This is successfully run by maven during the test phase, outputs a coverage.xml and nosetests.xml which appears to contain valid content and are in the target folder of the build.

```
user@user target  cat nosetests.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testsuite name="nosetests" tests="13" errors="2" failures="0" skip="0"><testcase classname="*snip*" name="test_a" time="0.035">
```

In maven, the structure is a multi-module pom, in the parent, sonar variables are configured.

```
<sonar.language>py</sonar.language>
<sonar.python.xunit.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/nosetests.xml</sonar.python.xunit.reportPath>
<sonar.python.coverage.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage.xml</sonar.python.coverage.reportPath>
<sonar.sources>src/main/python/django</sonar.sources>
<sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails>false</sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails>
```

Whilst the child contains the pom that creates, packages, tests, etc.

When running mvn clean install, followed by mvn sonar:sonar -X, as far as I can see the plugin detects the nosetests and the coverage file, however when looking at sonar I can not see unit test results or coverage.

```
[INFO] Sensor PythonXUnitSensor
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Sensor PythonXUnitSensor (done) | time=3492ms
[INFO] Sensor PythonCoverageSensor
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] Parsing coverage reports
[DEBUG] Parsing integration test coverage reports
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] Parsing overall test coverage reports
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Sensor PythonCoverageSensor (done) | time=1321ms
**SNIP**
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 542ms, dir size=756 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 879ms, zip size=331 KB
[DEBUG] Upload report
[DEBUG] POST 200 https://sonar.local/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.example:django&projectName=DJANGO | time=104ms
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 106ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonar.local/dashboard/index/com.example:django
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at https://sonar.local/api/ce/task?id=AVXFLPhlOl8UXdQaHPyt
[DEBUG] Report metadata written to /home/user/src/django-app/target/sonar/report-task.txt
[DEBUG] Post-jobs : 
[INFO] Analysis report generated in /home/user/src/django-app/target/sonar/batch-report
```

So the source code, complexity, etc. appear but neither the unit test results (at the path above) or the coverage is displayed.

Versions:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</plugin>
```

SonarQube: Version 5.5
Python Plugin: Version 1.5

Edit: Updated SonarQube to version 5.6, python to 1.6-SNAPSHOT

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1-SNAPSHOT:sonar -X -o
---
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Processing report '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml'
[DEBUG] Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'maven.tests.TestMavenVersionsViewSet'
[DEBUG] Using the key 'maven/tests/TestMavenVersionsViewSet.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[DEBUG] Using the key 'maven/tests.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[WARNING] The resource for 'maven.tests.TestMavenVersionsViewSet' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
[DEBUG] Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'audit.tests.TestSortDeploys'
[DEBUG] Using the key 'audit/tests/TestSortDeploys.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[DEBUG] Using the key 'audit/tests.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[WARNING] The resource for 'audit.tests.TestSortDeploys' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
[INFO] Sensor PythonXUnitSensor (done) | time=4195ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: svn
[INFO] 1 files to be analyzed
[DEBUG] Working directory: /home/user/src/django-app/code
[DEBUG] Annotate file src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py
[DEBUG] File [moduleKey=internal.build.services:audit_ws-site, relative=src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py, basedir=/home/user/src/django-app/code] is not versionned or contains local modifications. Skipping it.
[INFO] 0/1 files analyzed
[WARNING] Missing blame information for the following files:
[WARNING]   * /home/user/src/django-app/code/src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py
[WARNING] This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=1521ms
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (wrapped)
[DEBUG] Metric lines is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
*SNIP*
[INFO] Python unit test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Parsing report '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml'
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/JiraSoap.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/admin.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'config_item/autocomplete_light_registry.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'config_item/forms.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/models.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/productws.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/renderers.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard/serializers.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit_ws/settings.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/tasks.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/urls.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/views.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit/management.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit/management/commands.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/templatetags.py', ignoring coverage measures
[INFO] Python integration test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.itReportPath using default pattern coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml
[INFO] Python overall test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.overallReportPath using default pattern coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=3057ms
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=82ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
[INFO] DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for py
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Processing report '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml'
[DEBUG] Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'maven.tests.TestMavenVersionsViewSet'
[DEBUG] Using the key 'maven/tests/TestMavenVersionsViewSet.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[DEBUG] Using the key 'maven/tests.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[WARNING] The resource for 'maven.tests.TestMavenVersionsViewSet' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
[DEBUG] Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'audit.tests.TestSortDeploys'
[DEBUG] Using the key 'audit/tests/TestSortDeploys.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[DEBUG] Using the key 'audit/tests.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[WARNING] The resource for 'audit.tests.TestSortDeploys' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
[INFO] Sensor PythonXUnitSensor (done) | time=4195ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: svn
[INFO] 1 files to be analyzed
[DEBUG] Working directory: /home/user/src/django-app/code
[DEBUG] Annotate file src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py
[DEBUG] File [moduleKey=internal.build.services:audit_ws-site, relative=src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py, basedir=/home/user/src/django-app/code] is not versionned or contains local modifications. Skipping it.
[INFO] 0/1 files analyzed
[WARNING] Missing blame information for the following files:
[WARNING]   * /home/user/src/django-app/code/src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py
[WARNING] This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=1521ms
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (wrapped)
[DEBUG] Metric lines is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
*SNIP*
[INFO] Python unit test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Parsing report '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml'
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/JiraSoap.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/admin.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'config_item/autocomplete_light_registry.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'config_item/forms.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/models.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/productws.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/renderers.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard/serializers.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit_ws/settings.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/tasks.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/urls.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/views.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit/management.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit/management/commands.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/templatetags.py', ignoring coverage measures
[INFO] Python integration test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.itReportPath using default pattern coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml
[INFO] Python overall test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.overallReportPath using default pattern coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=3057ms
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=82ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
[INFO] DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for py
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Processing report '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/nosetests.xml'
[DEBUG] Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'maven.tests.TestMavenVersionsViewSet'
[DEBUG] Using the key 'maven/tests/TestMavenVersionsViewSet.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[DEBUG] Using the key 'maven/tests.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[WARNING] The resource for 'maven.tests.TestMavenVersionsViewSet' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
[DEBUG] Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'audit.tests.TestSortDeploys'
[DEBUG] Using the key 'audit/tests/TestSortDeploys.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[DEBUG] Using the key 'audit/tests.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
[WARNING] The resource for 'audit.tests.TestSortDeploys' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
[INFO] Sensor PythonXUnitSensor (done) | time=4195ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: svn
[INFO] 1 files to be analyzed
[DEBUG] Working directory: /home/user/src/django-app/code
[DEBUG] Annotate file src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py
[DEBUG] File [moduleKey=internal.build.services:audit_ws-site, relative=src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py, basedir=/home/user/src/django-app/code] is not versionned or contains local modifications. Skipping it.
[INFO] 0/1 files analyzed
[WARNING] Missing blame information for the following files:
[WARNING]   * /home/user/src/django-app/code/src/main/python/audit_ws/audit/tests.py
[WARNING] This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=1521ms
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (wrapped)
[DEBUG] Metric lines is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
*SNIP*
[INFO] Python unit test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml' to find reports
[INFO] Parsing report '/home/user/src/django-app/code/target/coverage.xml'
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/JiraSoap.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/admin.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'config_item/autocomplete_light_registry.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'config_item/forms.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/models.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/productws.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'lib/renderers.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard/serializers.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit_ws/settings.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/tasks.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/urls.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/views.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit/management.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'audit/management/commands.py', ignoring coverage measures
[DEBUG] Cannot find the file 'wallboard_ws/templatetags.py', ignoring coverage measures
[INFO] Python integration test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.itReportPath using default pattern coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml
[INFO] Python overall test coverage
[DEBUG] Using pattern 'coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
[DEBUG] No report was found for sonar.python.coverage.overallReportPath using default pattern coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml
[INFO] Sensor Python Squid Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=3057ms
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor XmlFileSensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=82ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
[INFO] DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for py
```

I have doubled checked the working directory:
    [INFO] Base dir: /home/user/src/django-app/code
    [INFO] Working dir: /home/user/src/django-app/code/target/sonar

Is it looking for the tests and coverage relative to the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs, it seems that the report paths are provided as absolute paths.
Version 1.5 of the python plugin only accepts relative paths. 
That's a [known limitation](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-125) which is going to be fixed in version 1.6. This new version is almost ready and you should be able to test a release candidate very soon. That will be announced on the [SonarQube google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube).

Comment: I compiled 1.6-SNAPSHOT of the python plugin and installed this into sonar, as well as the latest snapshot of the sonar-maven-plugin. There still seems to be path issues.

Comment: Now, the reports can be found, but the file paths inside the reports cannot be resolved. They have to be relative to the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sonar.tests` property to your configuration :

```
sonar.tests=tests_folder
```